# How to safely rename rename Hyper-V vhdx & avhdx files?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, hyper-v-server-2016

I created a few VMs and made a few checkpoints, how do I safely & preferably quickly, rename **the files on disk**?

[image: file explorer screenshot]

I can easily rename the labels here:
[image: vm's in hyper-v console]

> Hyper-V Manager
> Microsoft Corporation
> Version: 10.0.19041.1

Comment: Why do you want to rename them? I don't think you can rename them, at least not very safely without removing all the snapshots. If it is just for organizational purposes you could move the VM storage and move the VMs into separate directories.

Comment: different strokes for different folks I guess .  Why would I want a messy unorganized file system?  @Zoredache